# Casting in wrapper classes

Tags: java, wrapper

```
   int k=(int)10.0;
   Integer j = (Integer ) 10.0;//compile time error
```

In the second line of code i am getting incompatible types error.my question is why it is not possible to cast wrapper classes in java?As i am able to cast primitives in java.

```
   incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Integer
    Integer j = (Integer ) 10.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot cast primitives to the wrong wrapper class, use `int k = Double.valueOf(10.0).intValue()` instead or `int k=(int)10.0; Integer i = k;`

Comment: You can't call `valueOf` with a `double` parameter.

Comment: @1blustone: you're right. I changed it.